Find the minumum point where two distributions that are significally different become non-significally different
I have two skewed distributions. One comes from times an event happened and the other from times the event did not happen. These distributions have a similar shape.
Through Mann Whitney U test I have determined that the distributions are significally different.
However, I would like to know how to find the point in where both distributions are indistinguishable from each other.
That is, what is the point in both distribution that makes the probability of the event happening drop significally?
Is this even possible to calculate?
From graphing the distributions, we can see that there is a significant change from jumping from bin 0-1 to bin 0-2, but I would like to determine this through an statistical measure.
Here is a picture of my distributions
